# Import materialize-css on React - $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, ecmascript-6, materialize

I'm having some problems to import materilize-css on a React project. I checked and it likes be something wrong with Jquery. I made the import correctly checking the samples, like it:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'materialize-css';
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css';
```

It made an error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at materialize.js:7581
    at Object.<anonymous> (materialize.js:8255)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap c1e5761…:555)
```

I checked it and it is occuring in this code part:

```
;(function(){
    var $ = window.jQuery, <-
            $win = $(window),
            $doc = $(document);
```

How can I solve it? Can it be a materilize js error?

Thanks.

Comment: did you npm install jquery?

Comment: oh it looks like its trying to get the global jquery. drop a cdn link in your index.html file

Comment: Yeah. And materialize too. I checked and in the console, it is showing this message too: warning  '$' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

Comment: There isnt a cdn import of jquery, just the default index.html when the react project was created.

Comment: Right, I'm saying to just add jquery the old school way in your index file, and remove the import

Comment: Good @azium, thaks, it is working ;)